# How to add objects to a custom registry without referring to adders

Tags: java, static, frameworks, initialization

I'm not sure if the way I'm trying to do this is even possible, but I'm trying to get a system where I can add objects to a list which are cycled through and used in the main game loop. Unfortunately, every way I've tried of adding the objects requires the framework to refer to the "mod" which I don't want it to have to do.

The closest I've gotten is using static initializers in the classes that add the objects, however they still require the class itself to be loaded, and the only way for that to happen is for it to be referenced.

What I probably need is some other kind of way to do this, I've seen that somehow interfaces could do it but I'm still confused.

Example:

Main class

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < Registry.animals.size(); i++) {
            Registry.animals.get(i).makeSound();
        }
    }
}
```

Registry class

```
public class Registry {
    
    public static ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

"Adder" class

```
public class DogAdder {

    static {
        Registry.animals.add(new Dog());
    }
}
```

The abstract Animal class has 1 method `makeSound()` and the Dog class simply extends it and has its own `makeSound()` code. Of course, this does nothing because the code in the DogAdder class is never executed because nothing loads the class.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for Java's [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html%20ServiceLocator) which allows `Dog` to be auto-registered via meta-data without ever being referenced by your Main.

```java
  ServiceLoader<com.mypackage.Animal> loader = ServiceLoader.load(com.mypackage.Animal.class);
```

This file needs to exist on the classpath of your mod `/META-INF/services/com.mypackage.Animal`:

```
com.myextension.Dog
```